# .NET Native compilation in Visual Studio 2015 (Windows 10) fails

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, .net-native

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro. I also installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional and uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Whenever I try to build a Windows 10 app in release mode with ".NET Native tool chain" enabled, it fails with two errors:

```
1. RHBIND : error RHB0007: Could not load input file 'D:\Projects\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\MyProject.mdilexe'.
2. ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"D:\Projects\MyProject\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.MyProject.rsp"' returned exit code 7
```

The same project/solution builds totally fine on my colleague's computer (also upgraded recently from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro with Visual Studio 2015 Professional).

I already tried to repair the installation of Visual Studio 2015 several times now without luck.

Also there does not seem to be any information regarding the exit code of `rhbind.exe`. I double-checked the presence of the `*.mdilexe` and `*.rsp` files. Both of them are definitely created and are not empty...

**Has anyone else ever had these issues or is it just me?**

**EDIT**
I should mention that increasing the verbosity level of the ouput log in Visual Studio does not produce more information about the errors. However, there are some warnings that come immediately after the first and just before the second error:

```
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks0' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks1' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks2' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks3' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks4' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks5' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks6' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
4>STARTPROCESSTASK : warning : Unsupported section type '.tks7' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\Native\corelib.native.lib(f:\binaries\Intermediate\\FxCore\x86ret\corelib.native\ThunkPoolThunks_x86.obj)', skipping the import of that section.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved the issue by replacing the folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative

on my machine with that of my colleague's. Then I restarted Visual Studio 2015, ran a new build - et voilà - it works!

Comment: Why did repairing the installation of Visual Studio 2015 not fix it?

Comment: Any chance you could upload that folder to help us out?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a mismatch between several pieces of the .Net Native toolchain (ilc.exe). In particular nutc_driver.exe and rhbind.exe. Perhaps your machine somehow had the rhbind from an earlier version of VS (Maybe VS RC from ~ May 2015?). It's a bit unfortunate that the repair didn't work.

If someone else hits this state it would be interesting to know the version information for these tools. They live under "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\tools".

Comment: I did not have any version of Visual Studio 2015 installed before I upgraded to Windows 10. As I said there was only Visual Studio 2013 installed.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have more to offer. Setup issues like this are a bear to chase down after the machine has been cleaned up. Glad to hear that you're sorted out though.